# Is there a way to show the scrollbar of ListView all the time?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

Is there a way to **always** show the vertical scroll bar of the `ListView`?

Answer (score 17):

Sure, it is possible. Try [View.setScrollbarFadingEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29).

Comment: Awesome works for me; in XML this is: android:fadeScrollbars="false"

Answer (score 17):

There is actually a very easy way to do this using following property in `xml` file.

`android:fadeScrollbars="false"`

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, make the client area (the area where you are placing the widgets in `ScrollView`) larger than the screen size. So scroll bar(s) will be visible all the time.